# Target bytecode always drop back to 1.5 in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version, bytecode

I have a collection of "Samples" projects. The toplevel project is empty, while it contains a lot of modules.

Unfortunately, I am often required to set target bytecode to 1.5.

I did that many times from the beginning of the project, but it still drops back to 1.5.

How to stuck with 1.8 forever?

[image]

Comment: Are they perhaps maven projects? Because IJ will deduce the settings from the pom...

Comment: Yes they are maven projects, but I don't see any appropriate information in POMs

Comment: If you do not [define them explicitely](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) they will be automatically [defaulted to 1.5](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/). After updating the maven-compiler-plugin configuration you may need to reimport the project so that the settings get picked up. You can use the blue refresh button in the Maven window.

Comment: I have difficulties with your statement “*I am often required to set target bytecode to 1.5*” combined with the final question “*How to stuck with 1.8 forever?*” I have the feeling that there’s something wrong with your description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your pom:

(https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case (RHEL 7, IntelliJ 2019.3.1) was missing environment variable `JAVA_HOME`.